# How to use packages in EJS template?

Tags: node.js, ejs, timeago

I'm trying to use timeago.js in an EJS template. I have tried to export the library like this:

src/lib/lib.js

```
 const timeago = require('timeago.js');
    exports.index = function(req, res){
        res.render('links/list',{timeago: timeago});
    }
```

The route is:
routes/links.js

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM links', {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }).then((links)=>{
            res.render('links/list', {links: links});
        });
    });
```

The EJS template is:
views/links/list.ejs

```
<div class="container p-4">
     <div class="row">
         <% for(i of links){ %>
             <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div class="card text-center">
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <a target="_blank" href="<%= i.url %>">
                             <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase"><%= i.title %></h3>
                         </a>
                         <p class="m-2"><%= i.description %></p>
                         <h1><%= timeago.format(i.created_at); %></h1>
                         <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Link</a>
                         <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
     <% } %>
```

I need to use the library in the h1 to transform a timestamp I got from the database. However, I always get the same error: `timeago is not  defined`.

How could I export Timeago correctly to use in EJS template? If I require the library in the routes file and send it to the EJS template through an object works perfectly, but not when I export it from another file.

Comment: Can you show how are you exporting?

Comment: Hello, yes its the first block of code

Comment: I required timeago.js and tried to export it but I dont know how to do it actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following test program to do a minimal test of `timeago.js`

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const timeago = require('timeago.js');

let template = `
<% for(i of links){ %>
    <h1> <%- i.created_at %>: <%- timeago.format(i.created_at) %> </h1>
<% } %>
`;

const renderData = {
    links: [
        {
            created_at: new Date()
        }
    ],
    timeago
};
const output = ejs.render(template, renderData);

console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
<h1> Mon Sep 07 2020 00:01:57 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time): just now </h1>
```

So as long as you correctly pass the timeago object into your rendering data it will work.

The problem is likely here:

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM links', {
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        }).then((links)=>{
            res.render('links/list', {links: links});
        });
    });
```

Where you are not passing in the timeago object. This line:

```
res.render('links/list', {links: links});
```

Should probably be:

```
res.render('links/list', {links: links, timeago});
```

---

Edit:

More complete example using file paths specified in comments:

routes/links.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();

const lib = require("../src/lib/lib");

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    lib.index(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

src/lib/lib.js

```
const timeago = require('timeago.js');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    const links = [
        {
            created_at: new Date()
        }
    ];
    res.render('links/list',{ timeago, links });
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that too and works the problem is that i want to to use the library from another file not from the routes file from here src/lib/lib.js to the ejs template views/links/list.ejs

Comment: I added an example of using the file paths you requested.